# TSQL Lock behaviour on Index Creation/Partition Switch

Tags: t-sql, database-partitioning, indices, locks

I currently have the use case of inserting lots of Data (3.5Mio Rows, somewhere around 200GB) into multiple Staging Tables and then switching them into the destination-Tables. Now, becaufe of the amount of Data, we discovered that it would be faster to insert the data into an empty heap-table, then creating the columnstore index so the structure is identical to the destination table, and then switching - all within one transaction.
All the Tables are in the same Database, but they do not depend on each other, so the best-case would be to fill table A-Stage and B-Stage at the same time, create the corresponding indices on them at the same time, and then switching them at the same time.
Obviously, with Creating Indices and Switching Partitions, there are plenty of locks involved. Now i was curious whether those locks can cause a deadlock at any point, especially when it comes to sys-Tables.
All Tables involved will get a SCH-M lock, and certain sys Tables will also get locked, but from what i can see, they get locked on PAGE/KEY/EXTENT level.

Now i guess my Question is:
Are the sys-Tables and other structures i might miss stored in a way that i can alter indices/partitions without running into locks, as long as those are different tables/objects that do not depend on each other (no Foreign Keys or anything for example) or will i eventually run into a scenario where Table B has to wait for Table A to finish before even starting, or worse, a deadlock?

Thanks in advance!

Tried Creating a Clustered Columnstore Index/Switching Partitons and saw that certain sys-Objects couldn´t be accessed, wondered whether this will cause locks in the future or if the locks for different objects will always work out

Comment: `ALTER TABLE .. SWITCH` is a very fast operation once locks are acquired, so even if deadlocks would be possible in principle (and I don't know if there are), it would be quite hard to encounter them. Locks are another matter: obviously your `SWITCH` needs to wait if the tale is in use, and this could take quite a while depending on what's running. Rather than attempt to rely on a yes or no answer, which could conceivably even change between releases, it's probably easier to incorporate a retry mechanism regardless, as there's precious little you can do to avoid locks on system structures.

Comment: If it was only the switch i would be less worried, cause as you mentioned, in would be quite fast and could just be restarted when a deadlock occurs. The creation of the indices, however, might take up to 20 minutes - if another index build and or switch would have to wait for that, or worse, deadlock with it, thats the worse scenario. I‘m just not sure whether this can happen if those were 2 different objects with no relation other than the same schema

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't. While I have no hard guarantees on that, this approach (where heap tables are imported, indexes are created and a `SWITCH` happens to replace objects) is exactly what we're using in one of our systems, and I've never seen locks or deadlocks for index creation across objects.